# Java, Realm, Tomcat, login.

Tags: java, tomcat

I have some troubling with creating a login with the use of Realm running a tomcat server with mysql. 
I've created the web.xml, context.xml and it works with a j_security_form for the pages that is restricted.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how I would make a page that has a login form already and redirect to the same page. Only different is showing that the user is logged ind and the menu changes. 
But how would I do that since action=j_security_form doesnt point to a specific page(The index page) And this is what I want. How is this done? I've tried to google the shit out of it. But must of them writes about glassfish and couldnt find what Im.

Just need a "simple" login redirect to the same page with username in session or something like that. 
Im stuck :/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to re-read section 13.6.3 (in the 3.0-spec) which outlines how all this stuff works:

1. User requests a protected page
2. Container presents the login page
3. User submits credentials
4. After successful authentication, the user is sent to the page requested in step #1

If you want to allow "drive-by" logins -- that is, skipping step #1 -- you'll have to do it all yourself. If you are using a 3.0-spec webapp, then you write your own servlet to handle the login attempt: use the new `HttpServletRequest.login` method to access the `Realm`'s authentication capabilities and perform your own redirects as appropriate.

If you aren't using a 3.0-spec webapp, then you'll have to write everything yourself or use something like [security filter](http://securityfilter.sourceforge.net/).